# Issue in EsmtpTransport.php in SwiftMailer

Tags: php, git, swiftmailer

I am trying to send email from my application using SwiftMailer. I have installed the SwiftMailer package using git with the following command in my project folder:

```
git clone https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer.git
```

This showed me that swiftmailer is cloned properly in my project folder. Now when I am trying to send email from my application, it is showing the following error:

```
 <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\myAppPath\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php</b> on line <b>211</b><br />
```

When I tried to get into the EsmtpTransport.php file, I found the following code written:

```
 /**
 * Returns the IP used to connect to the destination.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSourceIp()
{
    return $this->params['sourceIp'] ?? null;  //*line number 211*
}
```

The code I have written in my application is as below:

```
<?php
    $subject = 'SwiftMailer Test!';
    $message = 'Hi! This is a test email from SwiftMailer';
    $usernameEmail = "username";
    $passwordEmail = "password";
    try{
        $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.example.com', 25))
                        ->setUsername($usernameEmail)
                        ->setPassword($passwordEmail)
                    ;
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
        $message->setTo(array(
        "recipient@somemail.com" => "Recipient Name"
        ));
        $message->setSubject($subject);
        $message->setBody($message);
        $message->setFrom("email@example.com", "My App Team");
        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
        $mailer->send($message, $failedRecipients);
?>
```

I am unable to figure out the issue and tried searching the net and unfortunately not successful yet. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a typo in the code.  They wanted to use ternary operator but instead `:` they put second `?`. You doesn't use composer so you can just fix it yourself. Just change

```
return $this->params['sourceIp'] ?? null;  //*line number 211*
```

to

```
return $this->params['sourceIp'] ?: null;  //*line number 211*
```

or download `v6.0.1`, free from this bug, from [here](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/releases/tag/v6.0.1).

---

@edit
It's not a typo. It's [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). It has been introduced in PHP7.0 so I suppose you're using an older version of PHP. You should use PHP7+ because swiftmailer is aimed for this versions.

Comment: I tried using the version you mentioned. The above issue is now gone. But now it is showing another error  "Call to undefined method Swift_Message::newInstance()". Can you please help?

Comment: @CoolJavaProgrammer what is ```newInstance()``` method? There's no static method ```newInstance()```. You create new instance of class using ```new``` keyword. [This doc](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html) will help you.

Comment: this issue is also solved from the link you provided. Now I am getting error "Class Egulias/EmailValidator/EmailValidator.php does not exist". I am using dynamic recipient addresses. Is this class mandatory?