# Swift Issue with Cron Job

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am using swiftmailer 6.0. When I run that file from url its work perfect but when I run that file from cron job i stuck in errors like very first error is `??`

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting
```

when I remove one `?` than it give me another file and line number which has same `??` I replace all `??` into `?:` than I got stuck into another error which is about `try`,`catch` & `finally` in 4 files the didn't declare `catch` after `try` they declace `finally` directly.

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'finally' (T_STRING)
```

After all the effort I search this issue on stackoverflow and follow [this annswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085125/issue-in-esmtptransport-php-in-swiftmailer) but didn't find any solution and update swiftmail to 6.0.1 but didn't help me out.
this is my all code.

```
require 'Path to/autoload.php';
// //=======  SwiftMailer
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('sever', port,'ssl'))
->setUsername($smtp_email)
 ->setPassword($smtp_password)
;
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
$smtp_message = (new Swift_Message($subject))
  ->setFrom(['example@any.com' => 'Test Title'])
  ->setTo($to)
  ->setBody($message,'text/html')
;
 $result = $mailer->send($smtp_message);
```

Help me out i supend more than 3 hours on it.

Comment: Offhand, I suspect that the version of php your web server uses is a newer version while the version used by your cron (PHP-cli) is a different version. Try running `echo phpinfo()` from your web server and running `php -v` from your console and comparing the version output

Comment: `??` or the "Null Coalescing Operator" was introduced in php 7. I suspect your cli uses a version before that.

Comment: The `unexpected 'finally'` error would seem to indicate your cli version is 5.4 or lower, which is quite old if that's right

Comment: I use `echo phpinfo();` It returns `7.1.14` but how can check my cron version?

Comment: open your console where the cron runs and run `php -v`

Comment: I didn't find the console to run command

Comment: What OS is the machine on which the cron runs?

Comment: I am running cron job from cpanel of hostgator

Comment: See https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/linux-shell-basics

Comment: Alternatively, cPanel may have a terminal/console launcher button somewhere in the ui, Im not certain.

Comment: Can you give the updated command line which restrict the cron job to run in php7+ like `/usr/local/bin/ea-php70/home/username/public_html/test_crone.php`

Comment: There is no updated command per se, if you run `php -v` from a terminal on that server and it says you have a version < 7, you'll need to update the php-cli on that server to a version that is >= 7. You still havent told us what OS you're running or what the output of `php -v` says but you should be able to google something like `upgrade php-cli from X to 7 on Y OS with hostgator` (filling in X and Y with those values) and get some advice on the steps specific to your situation

Comment: I updated the php-cli version but didn't receive the email

Comment: See this question for debugging help with swift mailer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366289/swift-mailer-cant-send-mail-and-cant-find-error-logs

Comment: But after alots of tries I am moving to phpMailer and it works